# How to calculate each time a button is pressed

Tags: c#

How would I make the calculation update each time I press a button instead of having to enter new values each time?

```
 private void buttonNextMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int month = 0;
        decimal monthlyRate, annualRate, monthlySavings, balance, initialSavings;

            annualRate = decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            initialSavings = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            monthlyRate = annualRate / 12;
            monthlySavings = initialSavings * 1;
            balance = (monthlyRate * monthlySavings) + initialSavings;
            month++;

            textBox4.Text = balance.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = month.ToString();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

keep your counter outside of click event so it won't initlize every time you click button

**Like this**

```
 int month = 0;
 private void buttonNextMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    decimal monthlyRate, annualRate, monthlySavings, balance, initialSavings;

        annualRate = decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        initialSavings = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        monthlyRate = annualRate / 12;
        monthlySavings = initialSavings * 1;
        balance = (monthlyRate * monthlySavings) + initialSavings;
        month++;

        textBox4.Text = balance.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = month.ToString();
```